# "without consulting", or do I have to use "without consulting the above personals"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Contact persons:
> John doe - +14555555
> Jane doe - +14777777
>
> Please do not enter this room without consulting.

in the phrase "without consulting", do I have to use "without consulting the above personals"? to make it grammatically correct? or "without consulting" is just fine without any additional words?

Comment: _Without consulting_ on its own sounds odd, but you should definitely not use _personals_, because _personal_ is an adjective. I suggest "...without consulting one of the above."

Comment: Of course, *above* is also an adjective...

Comment: "without permission" would be the usual way of expressing this, and would imply you have to contact one of the contact people.

Answer (score 1):

*Consulting* is a transitive verb, and requires an object. Occasionally the object can be omitted and supplied merely by the context; more often, it can't and needs to be stated explicitly.

This is one of those occasions. You make a statement of who the "contact persons" are, and then you make another statement requiring consultation, but the two are not necessarily easily linked. You could be asking people to consult their own colleagues about whether it's acceptable to enter the room, whereas what you really want is for the named people to give permission.

The difficulty is easily resolved by the addition of the single word *them,* because the latest antecedent *them* could refer to is the people you've listed.

> Please do not enter this room without consulting them.

If what you have quoted is the entire text of a notice on an office door, then it would be best to reverse the sentences because you can provide who should be consulted with no extra words, no references backwards, and in a reasonably friendly single sentence:

> Please do not enter this room without consulting
> **John Doe** +14447777777 or **Jane Doe** +14448888888.